# Social SDK for Mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile

1. I want to let users post via Facebook, Twitter, etc. on Android? Is there a SDK that will let me do this easily?
2. I would like to know if there are SDK's I can use for Virtual Currency and billing.
3. Already using Parse and Flurry.

I am aware of HeyZap (only for games), GetSocialize (a bit complicated to do custom stuff). I have researched and found: papaya, scoreloop, swam, skiller, gree. But which one is best? Ideally, SDK is multiplatform, but I'm willing to look at Android only stuff for now. Also, ideally the same SDK lets me do both 1 and 2.

Thanks.

Comment: be aware that Apple will not allow any other option than there own In App Purchase for buy virtual goods.

Comment: ok, i believe google has the same requirement (although probably not as strict as apple when it comes to enforcement). are there any sdk's that make selling virtual good easier?

Answer (score 0):

See here for sharing:  http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

See here for in-app payment:  http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html

Comment: i'm looking for 3rd party SDK's

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out Skiller SDK? If you need more details please contact us on developers@skiller-games.com and we will be more than happy to answer your questions and see if our SDK is what you are looking for.